# JSP input comes null to servlet

Tags: java, html, jsp, servlets

I'm trying to pass parameter to jsp to servlet. And my code is :

**Server side :**

```
String kullanici = (String)request.getParameter("onaylayici");
```

**JSP side :**

```
<input type="text" name ="onaylayici">
```

When i run it on localhost `kullanici` variable comes `null`. Any solution ?

**EDİT :**

```
<form name = "main" method = "POST">
<td class="summary"><b>İsteği Onaylanacak Kişi : 
<input type="text" name ="onaylayici">  <br>
</form>
```

Comment: Please give us some more context , how the request is dispatched and where are you trying to read it . Some more code will be helpful !

Comment: On a side note,`request.getParameter()` returns a String, you don't need to explicitly cast it :)

Comment: Can you shown your form?

Comment: Where did you add the *server side* code, in another JSP, in the same JSP, in a Servlet? From your current edit, your `<form>` doesn't declare the `action` URL that will handle the form submission.

Comment: there is jsp and servlet. request is in servlet and form is in jsp

Comment: And how you call your servlet? Please provide the exact code. If this is your current code, then you're not calling your servlet at all.

Comment: Please post servlet where you getting the value.

Comment: i think you mean that you want so go FROM a jsp TO a servlet. If thats the case look what Luiggi just said about the _action_ sttribute. But if you are going FROM a Servlet TO a jsp then your only chance is the set the value directly in the _input_, similar to _this request.setAttribute("onaylayici", request.getParameter("onaylayici"));_ in your servlet. Then in your jsp this: _<input name='onaylayici' type='text' value='${requestScope["onaylayici"]}'/>_

Comment: <input type="text" name ="onaylayici"/> terminate your input tag. And show some more code.

Comment: @fGo Thanks mannn ! Reallyy ! :) if u write as it answer i will accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you mean that you want to go FROM a jsp TO a servlet. If that's the case, look the action attribute:

```
<form action='/MyServlet' ...>
  ...
</form>
```

If you are going FROM a Servlet TO a jsp then you could reuse current request attribute. You do it by settng the *value* directly in the . Something similar to this:

```
request.setAttribute("onaylayici", request.getParameter("onaylayici"));
```

in your servlet. Then, in your jsp this:

```
<input name='onaylayici' type='text' value='${requestScope["onaylayici"]}'/>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are only form's name and method, without the action, the JSP don't know where to send its arguments, and the server can't receive the arguments too. For example:

```
<form action="/servlet/Test" method="post">
  ... 

</form>
```

Comment: <form action="/servlet/Test" method="post">
        ... 

    </form>

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set your parameter value in `Servlet` and read it in `JSP`, then you need to do the following:

In `Servlet`:

`request.setAttribute("yourParamName", request.getParameter("yourParamValue"));`

and in your `JSP`:

```
<input name='yourParamName' type='text' value="<%=request.getAttribute("yourParamName")%>" />
```

Answer (score 0):

**My solution is :**

`<input name='onaylayici' type='text' value='${requestScope["onaylayici"]}'/>`

Note : Thanks fGo ...

Answer (score 0):

Your code is ok, but a small mistake . You have not set the request data to the response page. So, You have to set the requested data to response as follow:-

Change on Server Side -

```
//Get the data from JSP
String myDataInServer = (String)request.getParameter("onaylayici");
//Set the data to response by request.setAttributes
request.setAttributes("onaylayici",myDataInServer);
```

JSP (Client Side )-

```
String kullanici = (String)request.getParameter("onaylayici");
```

Now it will work.
Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know why but it worked for me when I provided 'name' attribute to input text.

My *Old code* which returned null in Servlet:

```
<input id="closure" type="text" size="25"><a
                        href="javascript:NewCal('closure','ddmmyyyy')"><img
                            src="drawables/cal.gif" width="16" height="16" border="0"
                            alt="Pick a date"></a>
```

Just putting **name="closure"** worked for me. Now it perfectly returns value of this input text into servlet.

```
<input id="closure" name="closure" type="text" size="25"><a
                        href="javascript:NewCal('closure','ddmmyyyy')"><img
                            src="drawables/cal.gif" width="16" height="16" border="0"
                            alt="Pick a date"></a>
```

And I am getting value of this input text in Servlet as follows:

```
String closure = request.getParameter("closure");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
< input type="text" name ="onaylayici" value="<% if(kullanici!=null){out.print(request.getAttribute(kullanici))} %>">
```

<% /***Hope this helps**!*/%>

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).